# Google Maps markers not incrementing array

Tags: javascript, google-maps, backbone.js, google-maps-api-3

I have looked all over but can't find an answer to this. I have a map that when I click on it adds markers to where I clicked. I am pushing those markers into an array but when I do one marker just seems to override the one that was in the array before instead of adding another index to the array. The array just always looks like this [me] no matter how many markers are on the map. Here is the code

```
addLatLng: function(event) {
    var path = this.poly.getPath();
    var markers = [];

    path.push(event.latLng);
    this.calcDistance(path);

    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: event.latLng,
      title: '#' + path.getLength(),
      map: this.map
    });
    markers.push(marker);

    console.log(markers);
    console.log(marker);
    // debugger;
    function removeMarkers(map) {
      for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
        markers[i].setMap(map);
      }
      markers = [];
    }

    $('#btn-clear-map').on('click', function(event) {
      event.preventDefault();
      removeMarkers(null);
    });

    $('#btn-clear-point').on('click', function(event) {
      event.preventDefault();
      markers[markers.length -1].setMap(null);
    });
  },
```

this is part of a backbone view if that makes any difference. I just have no idea why when I push a marker in it seems to override the one that was already in there.

Edit: Ok I just figured out why, every time I click to make a new marker, it is resetting the marker array. Any clever ways to get around this?

Comment: I'm manually adding click handlers because the buttons are outside the view. I know not perfect but I'm new to backbone.

Comment: Yea I'm going to go ahead and try doing that, things are getting a little out of hand with them not being in there haha

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are re-declaring the `markers` array on each call to `addLatLng` method (Also you're new event handlers and creating `removeMarkers` function and a closure each time)

Instead, you should keep the markers array as a property of the view as shown below:

```
Backbone.View.extend({
  initialize: function() {
    this.markers = [];
  },
  events: {
    'click #btn-clear-map': 'removeMarkers',
    'click #btn-clear-point': 'clearPoint',
  },
  render: function() {},
  addLatLng: function(event) {
    var path = this.poly.getPath();
    path.push(event.latLng);
    this.calcDistance(path);
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: event.latLng,
      title: '#' + path.getLength(),
      map: this.map
    });
    this.markers.push(marker);
  },
  removeMarkers: function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    for (var i = 0; i < this.markers.length; i++) {
      this.markers[i].setMap(null);
    }
    this.markers = [];
  },
  clearPoint: function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    this.markers[this.markers.length - 1].setMap(null);
  }
});
```