# rendering google map in backbone view

Tags: javascript, google-maps, backbone.js, google-maps-api-3

So I just asked this question here: [Google Maps markers not incrementing array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33269325/google-maps-markers-not-incrementing-array?noredirect=1#comment54341022_33269325)

And I realized I needed to refactor, so now im trying to render the google map in one div within the view while the other has the buttons that clear it and such. here is the current code in the view that renders the map:

'use strict';

```
var MapView = Backbone.View.extend({
  id: 'div-container',

  // Initialize the google map in the map key of the Map model
  initialize: function() {
    this.render();
    this.renderPolyline();
  },

  renderMap: function() {
    this.model.set('map', new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-container'), this.model.get('mapOptions')));
  },

  renderPolyline: function() {
    this.map = this.model.get('map');

    this.poly = new google.maps.Polyline({
      strokeColor: '#000000',
      strokeOpacity: 1.0,
      strokeWeight: 3
    });
    this.poly.setMap(this.map);

    var boundAddLatLng = _.bind(this.addLatLng, this);
    this.map.addListener('click', boundAddLatLng);

    var boundRemoveLine = _.bind(this.removeLine, this);
    $('#btn-clear-map').on('click', boundRemoveLine);
  },

  render: function() {
    _.defer(this.renderMap());
    $('#div-container').replaceWith(this.el);
    return this;
  },
```

this renders the map where it is supposed to be but throws a blank Uncaught TypeError from lodash and click on the map does nothing. If I move the _.defer under the $('#div-container').replaceWith(this.el); like so

```
render: function() {
    $('#div-container').replaceWith(this.el);
    _.defer(this.renderMap());
    return this;
  },
```

Then I get this error - Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'offsetWidth' of null from Google Maps, and the map doesn't render at all. I'm so confused as to why and have no idea what to do.

Comment: Why do you need to use replaceWith? If the container and map container do exist beforehand, why not just call rendermap without defer or replaceWith?

Comment: Also, you're treating a view as if it was a model. Try using another name for the root attribute map. It is a reserved word and I know for certain that using it in a Collection breaks things.

Comment: Yea I was wondering if that was messing it up, and it was! Thanks!

Comment: Don't you mean to say `_.defer(this.renderMap)`? You're currently calling `this.renderMap` and passing its return value to `_.defer`, that doesn't make much sense. Or probably `_.defer(this.renderMap.bind(this))` to get the right `this` inside `renderMap`.